# Trying to generate table from JSON file with bean tags embedded in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, struts, javabeans

I am trying to generate a table of data from a JSON file using Javascript but am having difficulty because of the `bean:write` tag. The `bean:` is getting removed, so only `<write name="offenderCountVO" property="addressCount"/>` seems to be getting parsed. Is this approach even feasible?

From the page that generates the table:

```
        // Build profile section from JSON file
        $.getJSON('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/json/offenderProfileJSON.jsp', function(data) {

            //alert('loading JSON');

            var items = [];
            var table = $('<table class="profile"><\/table>');
            var profileCols = 2;
            var td = "";

            // Build array of profile categories   
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                //alert("building items");

                // Check if this category can be displayed in this module
                var item = data[i];
                var modules = item["modules"];

                //alert("Start check");
                if (modules.indexOf(appName) > 0) {
                    // This category should be displayed
                    //alert ("Passed");
                    var label = item["label"];                  
                    var link = item["link"];
                    var name = item["name"];
                    var property = item["property"];

                    newCategory = { label: label, modules: modules, link: link, name: name, property: property };

                    items.push(newCategory);
                }
            }

            // Alphabetically sort categories by label

            //alert(items.length);
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                html =  '<tr><td><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/' + items[i].link + '">' 
                        + items[i].label + '</a></td><td>\u003Cbean\u003Awrite name="' 
                        + items[i].name + '" property="' + items[i].property + '" /\u003E</td></tr>';       


            }

            $("#testArea").html(html);

            //table.appendTo("#testArea");

            alert("Done");

        }).error(function() {
            $("#testArea").html('<span class="error">Error parsing JSON.</span>');
        });
```

The JSON file:

```
[
{
    "label"     :   "Address",
    "modules"   :   "AGNT,BOOKING,DIO,OMP,OTA",
    "link"      :   "offenderAddress.do?method=list",
    "name"      :   "offenderCountVO",
    "property"  :   "addressCount"
},
{
    "label"     :   "Assessments",
    "modules"   :   "AGNT,BOPP,OMP,OTA",
    "link"      :   "offenderAssessmentList.do?method=list",
    "name"      :   "offenderCountVO",
    "property"  :   "assessmentCount"
}
```

]

I hope I've explained the issue well enough -- I'm working on several different projects and my head is spinning right now, so let me know if you need any clarification. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to achive.. should bean:write etc inline or visible to the user?

Comment: The `bean:write` statement is supposed to only show a numeric value in the table, by retrieving the bean property (`addressCount` to show the number of addresses in the database, for instance). Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<bean:write>` is a tag understood by JSP on the server-side, at the point when the initial page is created.

Using:

```
'<td>\u003Cbean\u003Awrite name="'+ items[i].name + '" property="' + items[i].property + '" /\u003E</td>'
```

from JavaScript makes no sense because the web browser that includes the resultant `<bean:write>` tag in its page DOM doesn't know anything about Java or bean tags. When the browser's HTML parser sees `<bean:write>` it thinks only "that's some `write` tag that I don't know about, spelled funny" and not "I had better ask the server-side what it's value for the property of that bean is".

If you want the browser to see the server-side value of a variable, you must return that value itself in the JSON response to the browser, not just a name and value pair that only mean anything to the bean-based server side.

Note also that dropping unescaped strings into HTML markup is dangerous. Without HTML-escaping, you have cross-site-scripting security holes when any of the item values may contain user-submitted values. Use DOM-property methods to set element text and attribute values instead of trying to create HTML markup strings from JavaScript. eg:

```
<input type="hidden" id="contextPath" value="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>"/>
...
var cp = document.getElementById('contextPath').value;

for (var i= 0; i<items.length; i++) {
    table.append(
        $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').append(
                $('<a>', {href: cp+'/'+items[i].link, text: items[i].label})
            )
        ).append(
            $('<td>', {text: items[i].value_of_whichever_property_it_is})
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @bobince. I understood the server-side issue and the `bean:write` not getting properly translated by the browser. I'm still a little confused, though. How would I return the numeric value I'm looking for in the JSON response to the browser? I did see how you properly escaped the HTML in the code, though, and that makes total sense from a security standpoint. Although I will adopt this practice in the future, in this instance, there is no form on this page and no user-submitted data is being displayed here.

Comment: @Mike: Usually, you have a servlet returning a dynamic JSON response into which it can insert values. If you are stuck with only a static .json file, then you would need either a separate servlet which JavaScript can query for the current `addressCount` or `assessmentCount` value, or you would have to include all the possible properties in data in the HTML page in advance, for example as `var beanProperties= {addressCount: 1, assessmentCount: 2, ...}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have a cross-site scripting hole on *any* page, it effectively gives the script total access to *everything* in the user's browser session on the site, across all pages on the hostname.